# How to fix the range of x-axis in slicefit plot option in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

When I run the following codes to show the predicted probabilities of `y` (*binary*) vs. `x1` (*continuous*) at different values of `x2` (*continuous*), the range of `x1` goes from its minimum to its maximum.

```
proc logistic data=data;
   model y(event='1') = x1 | x2;
   store logiMod;
run;

title "Predicted probabilities";
proc plm source=logiMod;
   effectplot slicefit(x=x1 sliceby=x2=0 to 30 by 5);
run;
```

However, I want to show this graph only for `x1` values ranging from 0 to 20 with an increment of 2 if possible. I don't want to change my model. I just want to change the range of the display for the x-axis. How do I do that?

Comment: Usually the automated plots you get from procedures are not very customizable. I always export the desired data from procs in a dataset ; and then do my customized plot with `proc sgplot` or a gtl.

Comment: @stallingOne Thanks for your reply. It'd be great if you could write an answer telling how you would produce a similar plot by **proc sgplot** or **gtl**.

Comment: Add a picture of the kind of plot it makes/you want. Because I have never used those 2 procs and I have no idea what they do :)

Comment: Hi, here is an example plot: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/02/11/proc-plm-regression-models-sas.html

Comment: I don't need any plotby (stratifying) option though.

Comment: look for proc sgplot vline or loess